# How to solve "Texas Holdem" without an excessive number of nested loops?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I'm basically just trying to make a 2-person Texas Holdem Poker game and to account for folding, which basically just ends the hand, I've used a ton of while True: try: loops. I'm just creating this to learn things. I'm sorry if the very long betting sequences are obnoxious or annoying, I just wrote them out every time because I don't really know better.

It has worked up until I exceeded the limit.

I'm not really sure what parts are relevant to answer this question, so here's just a url to the entire thing on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/u4Gi4cP0

```
while True:
    try:
        while True:
           try:
               # many more loops ..
               break
           except:
               raise
        break
    except:
        raise
```

I just want to be able to complete a round of Texas Holdem.

Comment: And yes.. that many nested loops is problematic simply from a coding perspective D: Using state variables would probably be a good start..

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm very new to this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on state variables. I'll read up on it.